# Disable horizontal scrolling on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, horizontal-scrolling

I’m looking to disable the horizontal scroll bar on the iPad in Safari when on my site.

I’ve tried `e.preventDefault` but this seems to disable both vertical and horizontal scrolling.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Insert this in the head of the html page :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: how would you specify different width's, for potrait and landscape modes.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```